# How to use a permanent filter in a List component using and or operator

Tags: filter, react-admin, postgraphile

I'm building a food panel, in which there are some products. Everything was fine until I tried to split the products in postal codes so other users with different postal codes wont see the products not related with their postal code.

Every product has a text[] column type in the psql db, which is an array of the postal codes of that product. I've tried many things but the "filter" prop from the  component doesn't seem to understand what I'm saying.

I'm using ra-postgraphile dataProvider which uses postgraphile. In one of my tries I managed to filter the postal codes by using a filter withing filters prop that is something like this:

```
const ListFilters = (props) => (
    <Filter>
      <TextInput label="C. Postal" source="cpostals" {...filterThatFiltersMultipleFields} alwaysOn sx={{display:'flex'}}/>
    </Filter>
)

const filterThatFiltersMultipleFields = {
  parse: (value: string) => ({
    value: value
      ? [
          {
            cpostals: { contains: value }
          },
        ]
      : {},
    key: 'or' /* can be or, and etc... */,
  }),
  format: (value: any) => value?.value?.[0]?.cpostals?.contains,
}
```

This works as expected, and when I type a postal code the list is filtered correctly, but when I try to add the same format to the filter is not sending that filter within the graphql call.

The filter I need in graphql syntax is something like this:

```
"or": [
    {
        "cpostals": {
            "contains": "20280"
        }
    },
    {
        "cpostals": {
            "contains": "20304"
        }
    }
]
```

I've tried many ways so could use that filter in  the filter props, but nothing is working, and the documentation does not specify anything about this kind of filters. Any clue of how could I solve my issue?

Answer (score 0):

React-admin doesn't support filter operators, as there is no standard for them. But you can implement one either in your dataProvider, or in your API backend, and let react-admin use it via a custom filter name.

For instance, you can suffix the filter name with an operator, e.g. “_gte” for “greater than or equal to”:

```
const postFilters = [
    <DateInput source="released_gte" label="Released after" />,
    <DateInput source="released_lte" label="Released before" />
];
```

See https://marmelab.com/react-admin/FilteringTutorial.html#filter-operators for details